# boost 1.58 undefined reference

Tags: c++, boost

I have a project that has been compiling and linking for months with no problems.  A recent upgrade of ubuntu to 15.10 bumped the boost version from 1.55 to 1.58.  Now all of a sudden I am getting undefined reference errors.  I get the errors whether or not I use static linking or dynamic linking:

dynamic:

```
> g++ -L"/home/peter/workspace/icflib/Debug" -pthread -o "icfapp" 
> ./src/AdminModule.o ./src/CaptureModule.o ./src/FFTModule.o
> ./src/GPSModule.o ./src/ReportModule.o ./src/icfapp.o   -licflib
> -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lfftw3 -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient  ./src/FFTModule.o: In function
> `boost::filesystem::path::path<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry
> const&,
> boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>,
> void>::type*)':   /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:140: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry
> const&, std::string&)'    ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `processCommandLine(int, char**)':
>   /home/peter/workspace/icfapp/Debug/../src/icfapp.cpp:85: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string
> const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'  ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t,
> std::string const&, std::string const&, int)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:373: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp:373: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string
> const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'     ./src/icfapp.o:
> In function
> `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&)
> const':   /usr/include/boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp:155:
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string
> const&) const'    ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int,
> char const* const*)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:43: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string,
> std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'    ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::extra_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string,
> std::string>, std::string const&>)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp:77: undefined
> reference to
> `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string,
> std::string>, std::string const&>)'   ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >
> boost::program_options::to_internal<std::string>(std::vector<std::string,
> std::allocator<std::string> > const&)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/convert.hpp:79: undefined
> reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIlcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIlcEE]+0x38):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool)
> const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE]+0x38):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool)
> const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x38):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool)
> const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'    ./src/icfapp.o: In function
> `boost::program_options::typed_value<long, char>::name() const':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:19:
> undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'  ./src/icfapp.o:
> In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<unsigned int,
> char>::name() const':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:19:
> undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'  ./src/icfapp.o:
> In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string,
> char>::name() const':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:19:
> undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'  ./src/icfapp.o:
> In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string,
> char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string,
> std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:167:
> undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&,
> std::string*, int)'   ./src/icfapp.o: In function `void
> boost::program_options::validate<long, char>(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, long*,
> long)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:92:
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string
> const&)'  ./src/icfapp.o: In function `void
> boost::program_options::validate<unsigned int, char>(boost::any&,
> std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, unsigned
> int*, long)':
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:92:
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string
> const&)'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'
>   ./src/icfapp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30):
> undefined reference to
> `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string
> const&) const'    /home/peter/workspace/icflib/Debug/libicflib.a(DBO.o):
> In function `unsigned short
> boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::string
> const&)':     /usr/include/boost/date_time/date_parsing.hpp:67: undefined
> reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

static:

```
g++ -L"/home/peter/workspace/icflib/Release" -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -o "icfapp"  ./src/AdminModule.o ./src/CaptureModule.o ./src/FFTModule.o ./src/GPSModule.o ./src/ReportModule.o ./src/icfapp.o  /home/peter/workspace/icflib/Release/libicflib.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a -lfftw3 -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient
./src/FFTModule.o: In function `getLTETxtFiles(dboFlightConfig&)':
FFTModule.cpp:(.text+0x1146): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::string&)'
./src/FFTModule.o: In function `FFTModule::scanDir(ICFSocket*)':
FFTModule.cpp:(.text+0xe95c): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::string&)'
./src/icfapp.o: In function `processCommandLine(int, char**)':
SNIPPED...
```

Is there something different in boost 1.58 that I need to set different compile flags?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you compile *everything* with the same compiler & flags.

This means you need clean the build(s) and use the same compiler that was used to build the packaged version of boost (note that gcc will also have been updated as part of the dist-upgrade).

Any changes to ABI or (implicit) preprocessor directives can lead the header files to emit different (effective) declarations, and violate the ODR.

> What's worse than getting the linker error is that you might actually have gotten Undefined Behaviour silently.